# Tailwind CSS classes not working after page reload

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Whenever I reload my page whole ui is broken, only manually written css code works.
I unable to find out why it's happening , I am new to Tailwind css.

Below is my file structure:

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./public/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-tw": "tailwindcss build src/style.css -o public/style.css --watch" 
  },
```

style.css inside src folder

style.css inside public folder

Index.html

```
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

[image: Before reload]

[image: After reload]

Comment: Sometimes, browser caching can cause issues with updated styles. Try clearing your browser cache or using a private/incognito window to see if the problem persists.
Inspect the browser console for any errors related to CSS or missing resources. It might provide additional clues.

Comment: Hi, I checked using console, some css classes related to flex are not present after reload please check attach image

Answer (score 0):

Your Tailwind configuration file name is incorrect. It should be a JavaScript file and thus should be named `tailwind.config.js`, `tailwind.config.cjs` or `tailwind.config.mjs`, not `tailwind.config.css`.

Comment: sorry for that It's already tailwind.config.js, update above